# Is there a way to refactor class names programmatically?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently writing a tool for Unity3D that has code generation using CodeDOM. One of the requirements is to be able to refactor the generated class names, from within the Unity editor (by changing a gameObject's name in the inspector).

Is there a way to refactor a class name programmatically?

Comment: I'm not aware of unity's editor, but do try to use VS wherever possible with resharper.

Comment: @Aviatrix The idea behind the requirement is to enable our game designers to rename the objects that we generate from. Besides that, I save the name of my generated class in a component, so if I refactor from within VS, my code will just regenerate the class using the old name.

And Re-sharper FTW indeed.

Comment: Your plugin should allow the user to drag a component (MyComponent) and by naming the GO Enemy; it becomes EnemyMyComponent. Should that add some inehritance as well (EnemyMyComponent : MyComponent)? Because even if the plugin does rename properly, that would create new types and quite a lot of problems.

Comment: the simple answer is this is so unusual you'd have to do it entirely yourself programmatically.  Everts has explained a much easier / more logical / more typical solution, it may help you